# WordPress in a subdirectory behind a reverse proxy

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am running an ecommerce website on a dedicated Apache server. I also have a blog that is accessible at `http://www.example1.com/blog`, but the blog is not hosted on the same machine as the ecommerce website. To accomplish this, I've set up a reverse proxy on the main ecommerce server to serve `http://www.example2.com/` when people try accessing `http://www.example1.com/blog`. That second server is an AWS EC2 instance running WordPress using Bitnami's AMI with a firewall rule making it accessible only to our ecommerce server.

In WordPress, my Site URL and Home URL settings are both set to `http://www.example1.com/blog`. My WordPress server's .htaccess configuration is below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

For the most part this is working well. The main blog page and all HREFs on it begin with `http://www.example1.com/blog` as expected. My problem is that redirects are not being handled correctly. For example, leaving a trailing slash off of a post's pretty URL like `http://www.example1.com/blog/my-post` incorrectly redirects to `http://www.example1.com/my-post/` (note that the "blog" subdirectory is missing). This issue is also affecting our ability to use the wp-admin interface because it too is stripping the "blog" subdirectory from its redirects.

I'm sure there is something I'm doing wrong in the blog server's Apache and/or WordPress configurations, but I haven't been able to figure it out after tinkering with it for a very long time.

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

To clarify, on the blog server WordPress is installed at the site root, not in a subdirectory. It is simply being accessed as though it is in a subdirectory by way of the following Apache reverse proxy rule on the main ecommerce server:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off   
<Location "/blog">
    ProxyPass http://www.example2.com
    ProxyPassReverse http://www.example2.com
    Order allow,deny   
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Comment: Any solution???

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  Did you find a solution?  Thanks.

Comment: I didn’t find a solution I was satisfied with, but I worked around the issue by moving the Wordpress installation into a “blog” subdirectory. Everything works this way, but the directory structure is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

It's normally to happen like that. In your .htaccess file you have this rule:

```
RewriteBase /blog/
```

But your wordpress is not installed on your main domain but in a subfolder.

So when you execute http://example.com/blog based on the rule from the .htaccess file it rewrites the base URL and removes the /blog/

Simply modify the .htaccess file for your blog to look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick. After applying your .htaccess recommendations, when I run `curl -i http://www.example1.com/blog/my-post` from a client, I still receive the following location header: `Location: http://www.example1.com/my-post/`.

I think the main misunderstanding is that on the blog server WordPress is installed at the site root, not in a subdirectory. I'll edit my original question above to clarify this.